# ReactJs Component not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm a newbie to reactjs and trying to test a very basic component, however it seems all my struggle is futile because its not showing up in the browser.

I'm using asp.net MVC 5 app and I've been following along this tutorial https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial_aspnet4.html as the tutorial states you need to add React.Web.Mvc4 Nuget package which have some dependencies.

My simple React component (SimpleComponent.jsx)

```
var ComponentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div style="background-color:antiquewhite">Hello World ReactJs Component!</div>);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ComponentBox />,
    document.getElementById('reactDiv')
);
```

and my razor view is pretty simple

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="reactDiv"></div>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SimpleComponent.jsx")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Any errors in console ? Change `style="background-color:antiquewhite"  ` to `style={"background:antiquewhite"}`

Comment: an error in the console says : The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX. This DOM node was rendered by `ComponentBox`

Comment: Oh just my mistake : `style={{"background:antiquewhite"}}` style must be a object. If u change on this and not working try adding in StyleComponent at start `window.onload = function(){ `  and close script `}`

Comment: nope not working syntax error

Comment: That's prove I'm retarded the solution was really simple change the style attribute to style={{background:'antiquewhite'}} makes it work

Comment: In react styles is different than in HTML. [Dom-elements-React](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Comment: That's clears the mystery thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution for my problem was to replace the style element in my jsx file as following

```
var ComponentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (<div style={{background:'antiquewhite'}}>Hello World ReactJs Component!</div>);
    }
});
```

Based on [react docs](http://using%20the%20style%20attribute%20as%20the%20primary%20means%20of%20styling%20elements%20is%20generally%20not%20recommended) "using the style attribute as the primary means of styling elements is generally not recommended"

by using javascript object to store the style as properties and I hope this'll help someone.